# Does the Java Robot class run in its own thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, awtrobot

In the [Robot documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) I don't see anything about Robot extending Thread. However, I am sure I have heard people say that the Robot runs in its own thread.

**So, does each instance of Robot run in its own thread, do all robot instances run in one thread, or do they all simply run in the current thread?**

Comment: take a look at line 129 of Robot.java : `peer = ((ComponentFactory)toolkit).createRobot(this, screen);` it does not extend `Thread` because it's most likely handled by the JVM itself

Comment: @Yanick, this confuses me as that would make the whole application sleep wouldn't it?

Comment: the `Robot` class does not fire device specific events, therefore has no need to be threaded, and thus runs in the same thread. Moreover, it does not directly pull device statuses, but uses a `RobotPeer` instance returned by the JVM toolkit implementation (most likely). The underlaying implementation is OS dependent, but I'm going off topic. Bottom line is that the `Robot` class does not have it's own thread, but registers a peer unto the OS event queue to be notified of interested device events, which notification happen it it's own thread.

Comment: @Yanick does that mean that robot.delay sleeps eg. the interface handling as well when the robot was created in the same thread?

Comment: `robot.delay(ms);` is a shortcut of (i.e. exactly the same as) `Thread.sleep(ms);`. It does not put to sleep everything, but the calling thread! In a multi-threaded environment, the creating thread is often not the only calling one; actually more than one thread could call `robot.delay(ms);` at the same time, except that the method is synchronized (i.e. exclusive, use `Thread.sleep(ms);` instead). The method is more or less simply there to give a coherent interface and allow delays (i.e. let the JVM receive OS notifications) in the interested thread before pulling device statuses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Robot` class runs in the current thread. There's nothing in the [source](http://kickjava.com/src/java/awt/Robot.java.htm) that starts a `Thread`. You can verify it easily enough too, just run this in Eclipse and look at the threads in Debug view:

```
List<Robot> robots = new ArrayList<Robot>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    robots.add(new Robot());
}
Thread.sleep(60000);
```

Comment: does that make the java application sleep when the robot is delayed using robot.delay? Because I believe it calls thread.sleep?

Comment: It'll sleep the current thread that you call `robot.delay()` from. If the current thread is the main thread it'll pause the application. The `Thread.sleep()` call in `Robot` is to a static method that can be called from anywhere.